# Getting series from doughnut chart - achartengine

Tags: java, android, achartengine, series

I am using a doughnut chart through achartengine and it is working fine except I can't figure out how to get the values associated with the region a user clicks on. It is my understanding through reading other questions that this is possible but the posted fixes aren't working for me. I have tried an onClick/Touch listener using getCurrentSeriesAndPoint but this always returns null. Here is my code:

```
final GraphicalView gV = new DoughnutChart().getView(getBaseContext(),
regionNames, regionSizes);

gV.setClickable(true);
gV.setFocusable(true);
gV.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        SeriesSelection selection = gV.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
        double[] xy = gV.toRealPoint(0);
        if (selection == null) {
            //update
        } else {
            //update
        }
    }
});
```

Let me know if there is any more information I can add.
My end goal will be to extract the name of the region clicked and then call another activity with that name to display more information about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The click and get selection is currently implemented for `XYChart`(line, bar,...) and for the `PieChart`, so there is no such support for the `DoughnutChart` yet.

Comment: Hi Dan, not sure if you will see this or not but I wanted to let you know that I devised a scheme for doing this with doughnut charts. Not sure if this is in development or not but I've almost got it fully functional, I just need to put tighter bounds on the acceptable click area.

Comment: If you get it to work then I suggest you create an issue and add a patch here: http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/issues/list

Comment: All right, I now have it working properly but I don't necessarily think it goes along with the conventions established by aChartEngine. How does the issue/patch process work? Will this be a problem?